# Hide blank rows in Dojo data grid

Tags: xpages

I have a Dojo data grid that displays data from a REST service of type viewItemFileService.  I have chosen this type because I need to allow the user to update entries and save them to the backend.

The REST service pulls from a view that is categorized, the view is categorized by the unique ID of the related document.   The 'keys' property is used to tell the REST service what values to pull.  When I was using a viewJsonService this all worked fine.  I had to change when I discovered that you couldn't save updates with that type.

The REST service appears to only return the correct view entry when 'pathInfo' to view in browser.  What is different that the viewJsonService is an entry for @toplevelentries that lists the total docs in the view.   The blank rows in the data grid correspond to that number.

Note: contentType of REST service set to "application/json"

I want to only show rows, where there is data, and no empty rows containing only "---".   For screen shots showing the problem, please go here and scroll to the bottom:  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/07/creating-updatable-rest-service-for-use.html

Comment: There seems to be an issue with viewItemFileService REST service. It returns in json value "@toplevelentries" the number of **all** view entries instead of only by "keys" selected entries. You can test it if you reduce view categories to the selected keys only.

Comment: So you are saying that this is a bug in Notes.  If I delete all other documents it works.  Can a REST service be tied to a NotesDocumentCollection, I will research that, but I am thinking no.  Strange that it seems that no many have discovered this before.  I am going to leave this open in case anyone has a work around.

Comment: You may find here the answer from [here](http://xcellerant.net/2014/01/23/dojo-data-grid-part-35-suppressing-blank-rows-due-to-readers-fields/)